# How do I extract only the second word of a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

I'm trying to figure out how to just show the second word in the vendor name, but I keep getting an error with the following code:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(
SUBSTR(vendor_name,CHARINDEX(' ',vendor_name)+1,len(vendor_name)),1,CHARINDEX(' ',
SUBSTR(vendor_name,CHARINDEX(' ',vendor_name)+1,len(vendor_name)))
)
FROM vendors
```

Can someone help please

Comment: How are you defining "word"?  Based on spaces?  Is the "second word" actually the "last word"? Give us some sample vendor names so we see what you're working with.  Probably you're going to wind up using a regular expression.

Comment: What is the error?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Federal Express Corporation

Comment: United Parcel Service, Roadway Package System, Inc, Yesmed, Inc...Those are some sample of the names

Comment: ORA-00904: "CHARINDEX": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 68

Comment: The names vary. So if there is just one name the results should return a blank

Answer (score 6):

`CHARINDEX` is not an Oracle function. I think the closest match would be INSTR. You can also use REGEXP_SUBSTR:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( vendor_name, '^[^ ]* ([^ ]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 1 )
  FROM vendors
```

Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4afab/7/4).

Comment: robust in the face of ill-formed input.  Thanks!